# How to fix contentful paint greater than 4.0 seconds on mobile

Tags: google-chrome

Recently in Google Search Console, I noticed that I have 86 poor URLs on my website ([www.wired2golf.com](http://www.wired2golf.com)). In my search console, it says that the issue is caused because these URLs have a LCP of more than 4 seconds on mobile. This issue is only evident on mobile. Everything is find on desktop.

For most of these URLs, I believe the LCP is the featured image at the top of the post:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz5dU.jpg)

Am I correct in assuming that the feature image is to blame for the slow LCP? And what alterations would I need to make to these feature images to reduce the LCP for each of the affected URLs?

Thanks,

Ivan